A geometry question
DBC = 40 degrees
BAE = EAD = 10 degrees => DBA = 70 degrees
ADB = 90 degrees
DCE = ?
Rule: using sin,cos,etc is forbidden
                                                                  B 
                                                               *  **
                                                           *      * *
                                                       *          *  *
                                                   *              *   *
                                               *                  *    *
                                           *                      *     *
                                       *                          *      *
                                   *                              *       *
                               *                                 *E        *
                           *                              *       * *       *
                       *                           *              *   *      *
                   *                        *                     *     *     *
               *                    *                             *       *    *               
           *                *                                     *         *   *
       *            *                                             *           *  *
   *        *                                                     *             * * 

A D C (I don't know why but it doesn't appear, so the are the other nodes
